# Pass a Boolean Ada type in Interfaces.C

Tags: c++, boolean, ada

I would like to now how to pass a standard Boolean Type in Ada through the Interfaces.C package in order to call a DLL function.
The Interfaces.C package does not contain the Ada Boolean type since the boolean type does not exist in ANSI C.
I have a DLL function written in C++ whose exported function prototype has an argument of type Bool. How is this passed in the Intefaces.C package in order to call the DLL exported function?

Comment: Just to back up part of Adrien's answer, where is `Bool` defined?

Answer (score 4):

traditionally, in C, a boolean is represented with an `int` type. in C++, a `bool` type is defined, but note the lowercase 'b'. if your argument is of type `Bool` (note the uppercase 'B') then you should have a class declaration somewhere (in your C++ library) which will tell you more about the implementation of the type. generally, such a Bool class is made compatible with a standard bool type through some artifact of the language: the Bool class defines no virtual function and keeps its value in a member judiciously placed first in the definition of the class.

i did not test it, but i would say you can go with an `int` type. make a test to be sure it is accepted by the C++ function. for converting from Boolean to `int`, you may use something like `Interfaces.C.int(Boolean'Pos(your_bool_value))`.

also note that, as specified in the Ada Reference Manual [B.3.62]: `An implementation may provide additional declarations in the C interface packages.` so check your implementation of `Interfaces.C`, it may contain a definition for a `bool` type.

Comment: I don't know about `Bool`, but `BOOL` is typedef'ed in WinDef.h on my system as `int`

Answer (score 0):

```
type Boolean_2_Int is (Bool : Boolean := False) is
record
    I : Interfaces.C.Unsigned_Long := 0;
    case Bool is
       when True => 
          I := 1;
       when False => 
          I := 0;
    end case;
end record;
```